# Any website builder / blogging platform that has Math Editor in the Rich Content Editor?

Tags: blog, squarespace, weebly, wix

I am looking for a website builder / blogging platform that has Math Editor in the Rich Content Editor[1]

Any suggestions?

1.https://community.canvaslms.com/docs/DOC-12859-4152724160